# what is "new classname(){variables}" in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a unity developer. But I do not have a lot of c# knowledge, because, I spent most of my time on Java. Today I came across a code in unity that I can not understand:

```
new IDs(){{ kProductNameAppleSubscription, AppleAppStore.Name },{ kProductNameGooglePlaySubscription, GooglePlay.Name },}
```

Now My question is: what has been done here? A constructor has been called and after that a new paranthesis and some variables?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? It looks like a combination of _object initializer_ and _array/collection intializers_.

Comment: If you can, please show the declaration of the `IDs` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a C# collection initializer. You essentially called Add() twice. What object you have actually created depends on *ID* class. *ID* class must implement *ICollection* interface for this code to work.

```
var me = new List<string>() { {"some string"}, { "string"} };
```

Comment: You surely mean `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable`. But even that would not be correct. It only needs an `Add()` method, no matter if or which interface declared that. `IEnumerable` has no `Add()`.

Comment: True, René Vogt, sorry, my mistake, I just followed my IntelliSense suggestion. I've updated my answer. Thanks